Automatic security update of google cloud function images
I'm having trouble fully understanding the best way to update cloud functions images to get rid of vulnerabilities inside them.
From what I understand from here, there are 2 update policies - Automatic and On deployment. I have some google cloud functions deployed (python3.11 runtime) and I see from "gcloud functions describe <function_name>" that there is a "automaticUpdatePolicy: {}" field which (from what I understand) means that Automatic update policy is on. However I'm not sure that the images are automatically updating. I see that some images that corresponds to some cloud functions have updated automatically but some are last updated months ago. Maybe Automatic Update somehow checks if cloud function is still used? I can't find more details about how this works in documentation. On few images there is a Critical vulnerability ,with available fixed package version, which I should fix in few days according to SLA but I don't know how can I speed up the process. I've redeployed the function and it solved few of Medium vulnerabilities but the Critical one remains.
It would be best for me to have some status of next automatic update or maybe to be able to manually trigger the update to latest runtime version. I don't know if there is some easy way to redeploy cloud function on your own image to have better control on that. What do you think? Do you have some tips & tricks to handle it, or maybe there is some better parts of documentation that I couldn't find that would explain more how the update process works.
Thanks for any answer, Regards.

According to this document Cloud Functions (2nd gen) now supports fully automatic security updates. Check the logs for each function and look for any errors or warnings related to automatic updates.

As an added observation, I noticed that my newer cloud function has the automatic security update checked, but not older functions which are being deployed as 2nd generation cf. Since the new setting only came in June 2024, I wonder if CF deployed before that were not retroactively set as automatic. When looking in GCP console, the check for auto security update were not checked for those older functions
